# How to eliminate variables with p value > 0.7 before computing stepwise polynomial regression?

Tags: r, regression, non-linear-regression, p-value, poly

I am trying to run a stepwise regression using AIC (through `step`) with 1,400 variables, but my computer just freezes. It works if I include <300 variables (after 13 hrs of running).

Is there a way to eliminate some of the variables (if p-value >.7) before I run the stepwise regression?

```
# Polynomial Regression
REG19 <- lm(R10 ~ poly(M1, 3) + poly(M2, 3) + poly(M3, 3), WorkData)

# Is there a way to get rid of variables with 
# p values >.7 at this point of the code?

# Beginning of stepwise regression
n <- length(resid(REG19))
REG20 <- step(REG19, direction="backward", k=log(n))
```

Comment: Could you add a sample of your data with `dput(head(df,n))`? Choose `n` as you may find sufficient for reproducibility.

Comment: Do you want to try something like this: `coef(summary(lm("Petal.Length~Sepal.Length+Petal.Width",data = iris))) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  filter(bac_tick_here_Pr(>|t|) another_back_tick_here < 0.00000002)`?

Comment: I strongly urge you to consult a statistician. Your basic approach is already very dubious but your p-value cut-off makes it even worse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you probably want is to exclude anything about the highest polynom where `p <= .7` (lower degrees should be kept). Supposed you know what you're doing, you could write a function `degAna()` that analyzes the degrees of each polynomial and apply it to the coefficients matrix obtained by `summary`.

```
REG19 <- lm(R10 ~ poly(M1, 3) + poly(M2, 3) + poly(M3, 3) + poly(M4, 3) +
              poly(M5, 3) + poly(M6, 3) + poly(M7, 3) + poly(M8, 3) + 
              poly(M9, 3) + poly(M10, 3), WorkData)

rr <- summary(REG19)$coefficients
```

The function that detects highest degree with `p <= .7`:

```
degAna <- function(d) {
  out <- as.matrix(rr[grep(paste0(")", d), rownames(rr)), "Pr(>|t|)"] <= .7)
  dimnames(out) <- list(c(gsub("^.*\\((.*)\\,.+", "\\1", rownames(out))), d)
  return(out)
}
```

`lapply` `degAna` to coefficients matrix:

```
dM <- do.call(cbind, lapply(1:3, degAna))  # max. degree always 3 as in example
#         1     2     3
# M1   TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# M2   TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# M3  FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# M4   TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# M5   TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# M6   TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# M7   TRUE FALSE FALSE
# M8   TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# M9   TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# M10  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Now we need the last degree of the polynomials where `p <= .7`:

```
tM <- apply(dM, 1, function(x) max(which(x != 0)))
tM <- tM[tM > 0]  # excludes polynomes where every p < .7
# M1  M2  M3  M4  M5  M6  M7  M8  M9 M10 
#  3   3   3   3   3   3   1   3   2   3
```

(Note, that the `apply` will throw a warning if a polynomial has completely `p <= .7`, i.e. row is completely `FALSE`. Since we throw them out in the next line  we can ignore the warning with `apply(dM, 1, function(x) suppressWarnings(max(which(x != 0))))`.)

With this information we can cobble together a new formula with `reformulate`,

```
terms.new <- paste0("poly(", names(tM), ", ", tM, ")")
FO <- reformulate(terms.new, response="R10")
# R10 ~ poly(M1, 3) + poly(M2, 3) + poly(M3, 3) + poly(M4, 3) + 
#     poly(M5, 3) + poly(M6, 3) + poly(M7, 1) + poly(M8, 3) + poly(M9, 
#     2) + poly(M10, 3)
```

with which we finally can do the desired shortened regression.

```
REG19.2 <- lm(FO, WorkData)

n <- length(resid(REG19.2))
REG20.2 <- step(REG19.2, direction="backward", k=log(n))
# [...]
```

***Simulated Data***

```
set.seed(42)
M1 <- rnorm(1e3)
M2 <- rnorm(1e3)
M3 <- rnorm(1e3)
M4 <- rnorm(1e3)
M5 <- rnorm(1e3)
M6 <- rnorm(1e3)
M7 <- rnorm(1e3)
M8 <- rnorm(1e3)
M9 <- rnorm(1e3)
M10 <- rnorm(1e3)
R10 <- 6 + 5*M1^3 + 4.5*M2^3 + 4*M3^2 + 3.5*M4 + 3*M5 + 2.5*M6 + 2*M7 + 
  .5*rnorm(1e3, 1, sd=20)
WorkData <- data.frame(M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8, M9, M10, R10)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but I got like 50 rows of this error after this line of code:           
"tM <- apply(dM, 1, function(x) max(which(x != 0)))"........................"Infno non-missing arguments to max; returning -Infno non-missing arguments to max; returning -Infno non-missing arguments to max; returning -Infno non-missing arguments to max; returning -Infno non-missing arguments to max; returning -Infno non-missing arguments to max; returning -"

Comment: I did suppressWarnings() and it worked, but is that *legal*?

Comment: Yes, I just added this to my answer with some explanation. When you check the output of the concerned line you'll find `-Inf` which indicates that no `x != 0`. We throw this cases out in the next line where we subset with `tM[tM > 0] `. These are just those cases where no polynomial degree had `p<= .7` and will no more be included in the new formula. Ok?

Comment: Thanks, but when one of the variables such as M6 is FALSE for all 3, the reformulate step still puts M6 back in (instead of removing M6 from reformulate step). [link] (https://ibb.co/rv6bBqx). For example, M65=2, but reformate makes M7=2 because M65 is the 7th variable included from the beginning (as the others were removed).

Comment: Thanks, that was an error in the `terms.new` line which referred rather back to `dM`  instead of `tM`. I've changed it, does it work now?

Comment: PERFECT! You are THE BEST!